# Child thread freezes until script ends when calling mutagen function, no errors

Tags: python, multithreading

So I'm working on a music player in python and when I init the main window it starts a thread that is supposed to get the metadata from files. But instead it just stops at the first import call in mutagens File function.

When I'm executing the script directly with python.exe it works without problems. But when I use the native python api in c++ to start the script, the thread that calls the function, freezes. However, I'm able to call the function from the main thread without problems.

main.cpp:

```
_putenv_s("PYTHONPATH", "python32.zip");

Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import cmw");
Py_Finalize();
```

cmw.py:

```
import meta
class MW(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(None)
    ... 
    self.m = meta.Meta()
    self.m.get(lists_of_files)
```

meta.py:

```
import mutagen
class Meta:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue()
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.result = []

    def get(self, files):
        t = Thread(target=self._work)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

        for f in files:
             self.q.put(f)

    def _work(self):
        while True:
            f = self.q.get()
            print(1)
            meta = mutagen.File(f)
            with self.lock:
                self.result.append(meta)
            self.q.task_done()
            print("Done")
```

Mutagens **init**.py:

```
def File(filename, options=None, easy=False):

   print(2)
   if options is None:
       from mutagen.asf import ASF
       ... imports lots of files ...

   print(5)
```

Mutagens asf.py:

```
print(3)
... All the code ...
print(4)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

The rest of the program works just fine. No exceptions no nothing. And when the script exits

```
3
4
5
```

EDIT:Fixed it by changing import to exec(open().read()) in main.cpp.

Comment: please write an answer and accept it, or drop the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okidoki. If anyone else have this problem. See edit